# Are there any advantages of using multiple threads for a file upload?

Tags: file-upload, concurrency, parallel-processing, io, network-programming

I got asked in an interview recently to design a file upload feature. After the initial discussion, The interviewer asked if I can design for multiple threads. My thought was, As the network bandwidth is limited and the internet is connected through a serial data connection, the network bottleneck will kick-in much before the CPU bottleneck, and a multiple thread implementation would have a limited performance improvement. But the interviewer was hell bend on the multi-thread approach. What are the arguments in favor of a multi-thread upload approach? (I recently came to know that AWS has a library which permits uploads on multiple threads. So there should be some advantages I am unaware of.)

Answer (score 2):

A TCP connection can be limited in rate even on a high-speed network because of the [bandwidth delay product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product).

> A high bandwidth-delay product is an important problem case in the design of protocols such as Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) in respect of TCP tuning, because the protocol can only achieve optimum throughput if a sender sends a sufficiently large quantity of data before being required to stop and wait until a confirming message is received from the receiver, acknowledging successful receipt of that data. If the quantity of data sent is insufficient compared with the bandwidth-delay product, then the link is not being kept busy and the protocol is operating below peak efficiency for the link.

One easy way to work around TCP limitations on connections with large bandwith delay products is to do multiple streams in parallel.